# Tricky "list index out of range" error when variable never exceeds list size?

Tags: python, list, manim

In my Python code below for manim, I am looping through a list while indexing with a different list of the same length. I have put a check to see if an exception is raised when i goes above the size of the list, which is n, and this exception does not occur. However, If the loop does run, an "index out of range" exception is thrown. The compiler says it was thrown on the final line of code I show.

> Moreover, I have already fixed the error by changing `vertices[i]` to `vertices[i%n]` in the last line. However, this seems like a fix that shouldn't work and I cannot tell why it does. If `i` never goes above `n-1`, then how could changing `i` to `i%n` fix the problem? Is the compiler expecting that I might exceed the allowable index, even though I do not?

The error only occurs when gammas is not initialized as None. Otherwise, it works smoothly.

```
def curved_polygon(vertices,
                   gammas=None,
                   **kwargs):
    n = len(vertices)
    if gammas is None:
        gammas = [None for i in range(n)]
    #replace none gammas with straight lines
    for i, g in enumerate(gammas):
        if g is not None: 
            pass
        else:
            print("here i is " + str(i) + " but n is " + str(n))
            if(i>=n):
                raise Exception("i is bigger than it should be")
            gammas[i] = lambda t : vertices[i]*(1-t)+vertices[(i+1)%n]*t ##straight line from start to end
```

Comment: `(i+1)` can be equal to `n`, which is out of range.

Comment: `enumerate()` gives you the full available range of index - you should never exceed it, but (as @PeterWood pointed out) you have `i+1`.

Comment: But `i+1` is given modulo n, so that also never exceeds it. Also the error is clearly not there because I don't have to change that line in order to not exceed the index.

Comment: If this function is called with an explicit `gammas` list, that's longer than the `vertices` list, `i` will certainly exceed the size of `vertices`.

Comment: The length of gammas is always the same as the length of vertices, and I have checked that in my implementation.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] so that others can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yes, I will provide that in a moment.

Comment: Still no [mcve] providing an example call leading to a subscript out of range. I suspect that @jasonharper nailed it and that you are passing `gammas` which are too long for `vertices`. You claim that this isn't so, but nothing else explains the problem as you describe it.

Comment: I've been unable to reproduce the error in a minimal context so far since the general project is large, but will continue to try and update this if possible. I wish that it was because `gammas` is too long, but I have fixed the error by changing `vertices[i]` to `vertices[i%n]`, and then printed the values of `len(gammas)`and `len(vertices)`, and they are always the same at every iteration. Yet, when I take the same code and replace `i%n` with `i` again, I am told that the index it out of range.